# Handling Declension in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I need to handle Declensions. The app is in different language(Czech), where the words changes for singular or plural. and based on genders as well.

**Example in English**

> 1 item, 2 items, 5 items, ...

**In target language => Czech Language**

> 1 položka, 2 položky, 5 položek, ...

I have found few repositories that I am currently going through. 
https://github.com/adamelliot/Inflections

https://github.com/mattt/InflectorKit

On android, there is a way to do it via xml. Is there any recommended way to handle this on iOS ? I don't want to use if's or switches.

Thank you for and suggestions.

Matti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS (and other Apple platforms), plural declensions and other localized strings that change along with numeric values run through the same API as other localized strings. So you just call `NSLocalizedString` in your code (no extra ifs or switches), but you provide more supporting localized data — in addition to the `Localizable.strings` file that contains the main (number-independent) localized strings, you add a `stringsdict` file for the declensions.

Apple's docs run through this step-by-step: see [Handling Noun Plurals and Units of Measurement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW10) in their *Internationalization and Localization Guide*. The example there is Russian, which IIUC has similar plural rules to Czech... but the `stringsdict` format supports the full set of [Unicode CLDR Plural Rules](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) if you need to handle more.